# SQL Server Conditional Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL query in SQL Server 2005 that is breaking when I include a conditional order by. When I remove the order by, the query works. When I explicitly write the order by condition (e.g. order by p.Description) it works. When I include the conditional order by, I get the error,

```
'Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type'
```

SQL Server isn't showing me which line of code caused this error. I'm wondering how I can fix this so I can use the conditional order by or troubleshoot which column is failing in the conversion.

```
declare @SearchTerm nvarchar(255)
declare @SortBy nvarchar(255)
declare @Months int
declare @VendorID int
declare @ProductID int

set @SearchTerm = 'focus'
set @SortBy = 'product'
set @Months = 3
set @VendorID = null
set @ProductID = null

-- This makes it so the @Month will filter by n number of months ago.
declare @PreviousMonths datetime
if @Months is null
    begin
        set @PreviousMonths = 24
    end
else
    begin
        set @PreviousMonths = DateAdd(month, -@Months, GetDate())
    end

select
    a.dsAlertID as AlertID,
    a.ProductID,
    v.VendorID,
    p.Description as ProductName,
    v.LongName as VendorName,
    a.Introduction,
    a.Writeup,
    a.DateAdded 
from
    ev_ds_Alerts a
left outer join
    tblProducts p on a.ProductID = p.ProductID
left outer join
    tblVendors v on v.VendorID = p.VendorID
where
    ( @SearchTerm is null or ( a.Writeup like '% ' + @SearchTerm + '%' or a.Introduction like '% ' + @SearchTerm + '%') )
    and (( @Months is null ) or ( @Months is not null and a.DateAdded >= @PreviousMonths))
    and (( @VendorID is null ) or ( @VendorID is not null and v.VendorID = @VendorID ))
    and (( @ProductID is null ) or ( @ProductID is not null and p.ProductID = @ProductID ))
order by
    case @SortBy
        when 'product' then p.Description
        when 'vendor' then v.LongName
        else a.DateAdded
    end

-- order by p.Description or v.LongName works when explicitly writing them out!
```

Comment: Make independent case statements to avoid data type cast error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per the previous answer, try:

```
order by
    case @SortBy
        when 'product' then p.Description
        when 'vendor' then v.LongName
        else convert(VARCHAR(25),a.DateAdded,20)
```

This should give you the sort you want, as it will format the date string yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

Comment: +1 Nice that you remembered to format the date as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to keep consistent order.

Comment: Performance wise this is a dog and would be better done separated into 3 SELECT statements with each getting run dependant on @SortBy

Answer (score 12):

You can use one case for each data type:

```
order by
  case @SortBy
    when 'product' then p.Description
    when 'vendor' then v.LongName
    else ''
  end,
  case @SortBy
    when 'added' then a.DateAdded
    else '1980-01-01'
  end
```

Comment: +1. I had not seen your answer and i have written something similar

Answer (score 6):

When using a `CASE` expression in an `ORDER BY` -- the data types returned must always be the same.

You can't cherry pick what you want -- INT, DATETIME, VARCHAR, etc. -- without using dynamic SQL or some form of decision logic (IE: `IF`) to breakout the different queries.

In this example you could use CAST/CONVERT to change the DATETIME data type to an appropriate VARCHAR.  But unless you know *why* the issue is happening, you're likely to do it again in the future.

Comment: That makes sense. What would be an appropriate workaround to using the case expression?

Comment: @Halcyon: Either use an `IF` to break out the data type handling for separate queries, or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Excellent explanation, but does not explain how OP can perform the order. As per @Neil and @gibeath: casting.

Comment: @Adrian: Casting works in this example -- that's treating the symptom, not the issue.  And I've provided two options for addressing the issue -- if the OP wants more detail, they can ask specifically for it.

Comment: This explains why the query wasn't working, which I didn't realize. gibeath provided a workable solution. Thanks guys!

Comment: Now if we could combine this with the answer from @Guffa!

Answer (score 1):

A NULL in a the list of columns to order by is ignored, so you can break them down by type;

```
ORDER BY
    CASE 
       WHEN @SortBy = 'product' THEN p.Description 
       WHEN @SortBy = 'vendor' THEN v.LongName 
    END
    ,
    CASE WHEN @SortBy NOT IN ('product', 'vendor') THEN cda.StartDate END
```

Bit ugly for the last else, better if you could;

```
 CASE WHEN @SortBy = '' THEN cda.StartDate END
```

Comment: I think you can remove  the second case from your answer and simply add StartDate. In the first case use an else to default to space. See my code

Comment: True, the difference is that would always apply ordering by date (after the other ordering) which may or may not be needed

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance, you might want a different approach:
1. Wrap your select in an inline TVF
2. Use two different SELECTs, so that they can get two different plans, potentially more efficient that the generic one-size-fits-all one plan you are getting now:

```
IF @SortBy='product' BEGIN
  SELECT AlertID,
(snip)
  FROM MyTvf
  ORDER BY Description ;
  RETURN @@ERROR ;
END 

IF @SortBy='Vendor' BEGIN
  SELECT AlertID,
(snip)
  FROM MyTvf
  ORDER BY LongName ;
  RETURN @@ERROR ;
END
```

Comment: This performance infinitely better than a case statement in the orderby clause