# Using 'LIKE' inside IF statement

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, sql-like

I need to sort a table using a condition. I used the below statement,

```
select * from table1 order by if (col1 like '%Cochin%', substr(col1,1,4), col1)
```

But I got an error, "missing right parenthesis".

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349677/conditional-order-by, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258376/mysql-conditional-order-by, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523954/sql-server-conditional-order-by, etc.

Comment: Use a CASE expression instead.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: There is no `IF` "function" in Oracle. You are probably looking for `CASE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CASE statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN col1 LIKE '%Cochin%' THEN SUBSTR(col1,1,4)
        ELSE col1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle,
Try this :

```
    IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(string, pattern) THEN
    .... 
    END IF;
```